# jquery .html() return empy value after text was inserted by jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Every time I click this function it returns 'Empty'. It should return 'Empty' only after the first click, but not after the second click.

Html

```
<p class="category"></p>
```

Jquery

```
$('.category').click(function(){
    var qBlock = $('#categoryId').find('.panel-body').html();
    if($.trim(questionBlock).length == 0){
        alert('Empty');
        $('#categoryId').find('.panel-body').html('111111');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ok try this

```
$('.category').click(function(){
    var qBlock = $('#categoryId').find('.panel-body').html();
    if($.trim(qBlock) == ''){
        alert('Empty');
        $('#categoryId').find('.panel-body').html('<div>111111</div>');
        // or use .text()
        //$('#categoryId').find('.panel-body').text('111111');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple simple mistakes in your code:

1. You're checking a different variable than you're setting: `questionBlock` and `qBlock` respectively.
2. There is no closing bracket for the `click()` function.

Fixing those two issues causes the code to run as expected:

```js
$('.category').click(function() {
  var qBlock = $('#categoryId').find('.panel-body').html();
  if ($.trim(qBlock).length == 0) {
    alert('Empty');
    $('#categoryId').find('.panel-body').html('111111');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="category">click me</button>

<div id="categoryId">
  <div class="panel-body">

  </div>
</div>
```